# Как подгрузить фрагмент в FrameLayout при создании активности?

Tags: android

Не могу разобраться как заранее в FrameLayout закинуть фрагмент так, чтобы потом можно было его динамически подменить. Пробовал такое писать в методе onCreate:

```
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_frame, characterFragment);
    ft.commit();
```

но когда оно натыкалось в коде на ещё одну строку ft.commit(); , то сразу падало, отбрасывая java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called.

UPD:
Получилось обойти это, использовав для один SuppoutFragmentManager для закидывания фрагмента во фрейм во время создания активити. Не знаю, насколько это нормально, может кто подскажет?

Comment: Нельзя транзакцию больше одного раза коммитить.

Comment: Изначально в активити только фрейм куда я в последствии должен их закидывать, там нет фрагмента в момент выполнения onCreate. А должен быть. И вот как его там сразу отобразить - хз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действовать надо так:

1. При первом запуске активити `savedInstanceState` оной будет `null`. - по этому условию добавляйте фрагмент в активити.
2. После поворота/смены кофигурации etc `savedInstanceState` уже не `null` и повторно фрагмент не добавится.

И да - транзакцию можно только раз закоммитить. После надо новую создавать.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо заменить фрагмент вызывайте не .add а .replace